# Resources for learning advanced javascript like the stuff written for jquery , mootools?

Tags: javascript

CAn anyone please provide me some resources where I can learn advanced javascript like the stuff written for jquery , mootools, etc?

Comment: Do you mean what's going on behind the scenes?

Comment: Yes, also I would like to learn how to write that kind-a code

Comment: A big vote up. There are countless "introductory" courses of Javascript - and the resulting code looks quite similar to C++ or Java. But if you look at the code written by JS masters, it's a completely alien language. It's a matter of changing the way of thinking, not just knowing the building blocks of the language. I would love to learn that.

Comment: +1 SF, Javascript is a misterious language, i couldnt learn anything in class, all i know i picked it up through blogs and forums and trials and errors, then i discovered this `var $ = (function() {})();` :)

Comment: btw, probably should be community wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can totally recommend Douglas Crockford's **"JavaScript: The Good Parts"**.

Awesome book. You should also [check out his website](http://www.crockford.com/) where he covers some advanced JavaScript topics (and how he ported Maniac Mansion to the NES).

Comment: Douglas Crockford created JSON, right? If suppose I want to create a feature & add that to javascript specification, how should I do that ?

Comment: abhishekoza: Yes, but more importantly Douglas Crockford created Javascript. Or at least was one of most important people at drafting the spec and writing the first implementation. If there is one person on Earth to teach you the advanced Javascript, it's him.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Patterns is a good book to learn object oriented programming and advanced concepts in javascript.